# Aspnet Core 3.1 Identity ConfirmEmail not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor

I am using the aspnet core hosted blazor wasm project type. I am attempting to confirm the user account via an email link that is sent to the user.

The email is being generated and sent. The confirmation link generated is:
    https://localhost:5001/accountconfirmation?code=CfDJ8L2gJclnoq5BioPxBNdLc8wCyaMHcitemYm7I8XKkey+M+vauvFOj0HN1meMs6JusAIMNd8gFCe/e8U0w3MMa0blmDzAMqrXGHvekYo5iPGeFlzLrY2guPO1iwAhUlQJ4t6ZRk5ieyGcgREID/9G8rwJKYC+Ct4WXtQiyfywGpixo63Y4B4hNdQquQE5trdzF0bOyeq2lJhbAlhe5TnsnGqiKbJq60oCuR07M/Gcp9URBLPYVCbG7Ymi+4BUUCRA/Q==&userId=5742c1f1-7957-4154-b12d-5e6e3eaebd0f

When the email link is clicked, the user is navigated to the Blazor front end webapp which then posts the querystring parameters to the AccountsController action. The values are received correctly in the controller action.

I would expect this action method to set the account to confirmed, but that is not happening. I also tried URL encoding the code but still no success.The userId is a GUID and is passed as a string.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(Urls.ConfirmAccount)]
    public async Task<IdentityResult> Confirm([FromQuery]string code,[FromQuery]string userId)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        IdentityResult result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug `result`? It should have more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **Base64UrlDecode**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(Urls.ConfirmAccount)]
    public async Task<IdentityResult> Confirm([FromQuery]string code,[FromQuery]string userId)
    {
        code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        IdentityResult result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

        return result;
    }
```

This is from a working example: https://github.com/ADefWebserver/Blazor-Blogs/blob/master/BlazorBlogs/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs

Comment: Hi Michael, I added your code but still failing : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager[0]
      => RequestPath:/api/login RequestId:0HLSKEIVKDL56:000000E7, SpanId:|e90a55c7-428f5fcd34ea0053., TraceId:e90a55c7-428f5fcd34ea0053, ParentId: => CommunityApp.Server.Controllers.LoginController.Login (CommunityApp.Server)
      User 7de630a5-51a0-4ad5-9f78-94d304df263c cannot sign in without a confirmed email.

Comment: Darn the only thing I can suggest is to pull down my project and run it. Perhaps the way I am creating the token is why it is working for me?

Comment: On this page I am calling Base64UrlEncode https://github.com/ADefWebserver/Blazor-Blogs/blob/master/BlazorBlogs/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs

Comment: Hi Michael - I used your exact code and it started working - thanks again

Comment: So the two pieces of code together are : ENCODING : var code = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code)); and DECODING : code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));

Comment: @Greg - Thanks for following up.